# How to place forms horizontal inside a td tag

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

I like to place buttons that links to different urls (meaning I have to use one form per button so that the action can hold different urls). 
The problem is that the buttons appears vertical inside the td. I like to see them horizontal. Any suggestions? float:left and display:inline-block in the td tag doesn't work.

```
<table><tr>
  <td>

    <form action = "page1.html">
      <button type="submit" name="btn1">btn1<button>
    </form>

    <form action = "page2.html">
      <button type="submit" name="btn2">btn2<button>
    </form>

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try it in the form tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now put style="display:inline-block" in each form tag and style="white-space:nowrap" in the td. It works.

Comment: Congrats in finding a solution, But  why didn't you replied to my comment? my answer is correct unless you have more code that you didn't shared

Answer (score 0):

Using `float: left` for the forms will work if there is enough space inside the table, so you have to make the table width wider than the combined width of the 2 form contents.

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  float: left;
}
```

Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/11x6art9/1/

Comment: this is not true, just see my answer, not using `width:100%`in `table`

Comment: I respect your opinion, but it does seem to work.  Its kind of the point of float left, if there isn't enough space then it will show the second button below the first, but if there is enough room it will show them side by side.

Comment: I just show you that it doesn't need `width:100%` in `table`, but see for yourself https://jsfiddle.net/nhqgtcn1/